# Killall waiting for response

Tags: centos, kill

when I do a killall java there is no response...However the next time I press enter I get a response.

Is this normal? Its ruining my cron job as it doesnt mail the killall output.

Using Centos 6.

Comment: Java is quite touchy, in my experience. It does not like to die right away, but instead will finish up whatever it's doing before exiting gracefully.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no response"? Do you mean your `killall` hangs? Or returns without any output? Or do you mean it appears to work normally but the process doesn't die? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `killall`, by default, is a polite request for the process to shut down. It may take its time, it may ignore it, it may fail to do it. A common pattern is to send a regular `killall`, wait a few seconds to see if the process has terminated, send another if not, wait a few more seconds, and then switch to more aggressive termination methods if needed.